# How to just see a full command that gives error in GNU makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu

When I'm compiling something, it gives errors like this:

```
$ make
CC    test/hello.o
test/hello.c:37:29: fatal error: this/is/hard/to/find.h: No such file or directory
```

Then, is it possible to see the full command of CC (with all the options) by just giving an proper option to make without modifying Makefile?

Comment: Could you post your makefile? My gcc and g++ usually expand the full command.

Comment: You've written your makefile so it doesn't show the complete output - don't do that. Or incase you actually didn't write the makefile yourself, but are compiling an arbitrary package made with autotools , do `make V=1`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a Makefile is set up to print summary lines like this instead of the full command, they also define a `VERBOSE` or `QUIET` variable to control that behavior.  You might try just running make as `make VERBOSE=1`, but if that doesn't work you'll have to check the Makefile to see if it supports verbose output through some other mechanism, or post some of your Makefile for us to see.

Alternatively, you could use something like [ElectricAccelerator](http://www.electric-cloud.com/downloads/software.php), a high-performance replacement for GNU make that, among other features, can produce an XML-marked-up version of your build log, including all the command-lines for every command invoked, even if the Makefile normally only prints summaries like you've shown.

*(Disclaimer: I'm the architect and lead developer of ElectricAccelerator)*